# Почему не открывается модальное окно при передаче get-параметра на страницу?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Допустим у меня есть ссылка: `<a id="data-trigger">Link</a>`. При клике на нее должно всплывать модальное окно, в которое я передаю get-параметр id с неким значением. Вот так выглядит функция открытия окна:

```
      let openModal = function() {
        modal.classList.add('is-open'); // modal - контейнер модального окна
        var value = document.querySelector("[name=t9]:checked").value; // выбор значения из checkbox
        var strLink = "?id=" + value;
        document.getElementById("data-trigger").setAttribute("href", strLink);
      }
```

Проблема в том, что когда вызывается эта функция, то сначала обрабатывается выражение открытия окна `modal.classList.add('is-open');`, а уже затем выражение добавления параметра в адресную строку. Одновременно эти выражения обрабатываться не могут: когда открывается окно, то пропадают параметры из адресной строки, когда появляются параметры - пропадает окно. Как это исправить?

Comment: `return false` в конец функции добавьте, авось поможет.

Comment: Впервые встречаю, чтобы в блок на странице передавали атрибут `href`. (видать, сегодня я ещё не употреблял 150 грамм)

Comment: по идее вы меняете атрибут уже открытого окна, а ван вместо этого нужно сделать редирект открытого окна на новую ссылку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вы в уже открытом окне меняете атрибут но не осуществляете переход.
Вам нужно открывать вот так:

```
let openModal = function() {
  var value = document.querySelector("[name=t9]:checked").value; // выбор значения из checkbox
  var strLink = "?id=" + value;
  window.location.href = strLink;
}
```

или

```
.setAttribute("href", strLink);
```

заменить на

```
.location.href = strLink;
```